# RESTful URL - Creating a resource based on a resource template

Tags: rest, http, templates, url

I'm working on an RESTful API, and I just encountered a designing problem.
I searched about it but I can't find anything about this specific case.

---

My API is used to buy tickets, so I have two types of resources: **ticketTemplates** and **ticketPurchases**.

Ticket templates are firstly created (defining a type of buyable ticket, with its name, duration and price) and when someone buy a ticket (= add a ticketPurchases row in db), it will always be based on a ticket template id.

There is an already implemented route for ticket templates: **/ticketTemplates**

Now, I'm implementing a route in order to buy a ticket based on a ticket template id, so this bought ticket will inherit the template name, duration and price.

I was thinking of **(POST) /ticketTemplates/[templateId]/ticketPurchases** to do that.

But because I have to be able to retrieve all ticketPurchases independently of their template id (so, by **not** doing that: **(GET) /ticketTemplates/[templateId]/ticketPurchases**), the only solutions I see are:

- Creation: **(POST) /ticketTemplates/[templateId]/ticketPurchases**
- Retrieving: **(GET) /ticketPurchases**

or

- Creation: **(POST) /ticketPurchases** (and pass the template id in the body of the request)
- Retrieving: **(GET) /ticketPurchases**

Which one is the best, RESTfully speaking ?
Is that ok if URLs are not the same for creating and retrieving the resource, like in my first proposition ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably more meaningful to keep the resource URL intact, it makes more sense and easier for developers to follow, rather than stumbling along other resources and discovering where it should go

I would choose

**Creation:** (POST) /ticketPurchases (and pass the template id in the body of the request)

**Retrieving:** (GET) /ticketPurchases

myself over the previous one

Comment: It makes sense, but I wasn't sure it was a good choice, REStfully speaking. Thank you, for your response !